# Way to make IIS ignore the domain name for session?

Tags: iis-6

We have an issue in a .NET application where the session isn't working right if the user does not have "www" in the domain; this causes application issues.  I'm investigating the code part to see if a change can be made there, but is there a setting that can be set on IIS itself?  I know that Apache has a setting to make it not care if the user has "www" or not in the domain and it will still allow the session; is there a way to do that for IIS or is this strictly a code-related issue?  The web server is running Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

In short you can't. ASP.NET these as different cookie domains and therefore you'll get different session ID's.

The work around would be to rewrite the inbound requests to a consistent address, either to `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`.

Comment: Okay, I'll look at that or alternative ways.  Thanks.